# Weird Vertical Spacing of '*' with Fira Code in Listings

Tags: listings, luatex, fontspec, code

I am recently getting started with LuaLaTeX and I was trying to set up a custom `listings` style for C++. Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\newfontfamily{\firaseries}{Fira Code}

\lstdefinestyle{mStyle}{
    language=C++,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\firaseries,
    commentstyle=\color{red}
}

\lstset{style=mStyle}

\begin{document}
    Default font text with *.

    \firaseries This is text in Fira Code with *.

    \begin{lstlisting}
        Listing text with *.
        /* This is a comment. */
        This should not be red.
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

This produces the following output: [image: First PDF Output]

As you can see, the `*` characters are way too low when used in the listing.

In an attempt to fix this issue, I added this line to my style definition:

```
literate={*}{{\firaseries*}}1
```

This yields the desired vertical position but unfortunately, it creates a new problem: Now the text after a multi-line comment is also red.

[image: Second PDF Output]

I would very much appreciate any pointers on how to fix this problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If I remembered correctly, the `/*` and `*/` are two pairs of characters which have ligatures in Fira Code. I suspect the problem comes from how `listings` treats the special `*` character.

Comment: BTW, simply using `literate={*}{*}1` suffices to get the `*` up. But still no ligature :(

Comment: @RuixiZhang Oh, that's good to know as well. I do not care about ligatures in this case anyway so it's not too much of an issue for me. :)

Comment: Still, I am searching for a solution that enables Fira Code's ligatures. Here is a comparison between Ulrike Fischer's nice answer and what I intended to work on: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CzUM.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although [@UlrikeFischer’s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/464546/164314) solves the OP, it is still worth mentioning that there are *hidden traps*. Consider the following “enhanced” example from the OP:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec,xcolor,listings}
\newfontfamily\firaseries{Fira Code}
\lstdefinestyle{LeonStyle}{
  language=C++,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\firaseries,
  commentstyle=\color{red}
}
\lstset{style=LeonStyle}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
Listing text with *.
C++  a<=b  c=2-1
/* This is a comment. */
This should not be red.
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image: HiddenProblems]

The hyphen-minus symbol is wrong, too. In fact, it is replaced with a math mode minus `$-$` by the `listings` package.

---

## The easiest solution

Don’t load `Fira Code` via `\newfontfamily`. Instead, load the font via `\setmonofont` and use `basicstyle=\ttfamily`. This signifies `Fira Code` as a monospaced typeface and prevents `listings` from replacing certain symbols.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec,xcolor,listings}
\setmonofont{Fira Code}
\lstdefinestyle{LeonStyle}{
  language=C++,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
  commentstyle=\color{red}
}
\lstset{style=LeonStyle}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
Listing text with *.
C++  a<=b  c=2-1
/* This is a comment. */
This should not be red.
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image: ttfamily]

---

## More elaborate solution

Over the past few days, I have written a small package `lstfiracode` (shameless plug). It is mainly designed to utilize the `Fira Code` programming ligatures in the `lstlisting` environment. If you are using `Fira Code`, then you probably want the ligatures (otherwise you could just use `Fira Mono`). Here is how you would implement `lstfiracode`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec,xcolor,listings}
\usepackage{lstfiracode} % https://ctan.org/pkg/lstfiracode
\setmonofont{Fira Code}[Ligatures=Common,Contextuals=Alternate]
\lstset{
  language=C++,
  style=FiraCodeStyle,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
  commentstyle=\color{red}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
Listing text with *.
C++  a<=b  c=2-1
/* This is a comment. */
This should not be red.
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image: ligatures]

The [`lstfiracode`](https://ctan.org/pkg/lstfiracode) package is now on CTAN (2018/12/17). It will be available on all the mirrors and the major TeX distributions in the next few days. Enjoy! `:)`

Answer (score 3):

You can raise the asterix like this:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\newfontfamily{\firaseries}{Fira Code}

\lstdefinestyle{mStyle}{
    language=C++,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\firaseries,
    commentstyle=\color{red}
}

\lstset{style=mStyle}
\makeatletter
\lst@CCPutMacro
    \lst@ProcessOther {"2A}{%
      \lst@ttfamily
         {*}% used with ttfamily
         {\raisebox{1ex}{\textasteriskcentered}}}% used with other fonts
    \@empty\z@\@empty
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    Default font text with *.

    \firaseries This is text in Fira Code with *.

    \begin{lstlisting}
        Listing text with *.
        /* This is a comment. */
        This should not be red.
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Something like this would work too (or you combine it with a \raisebox):

```
\makeatletter
\lst@CCPutMacro
    \lst@ProcessOther {"2A}{%
      \lst@ttfamily
         {*}% used with ttfamily
         {*}}% used with other fonts
    \@empty\z@\@empty
\makeatother
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! Although I have no idea why or how this works ... :)